# Observing the results of the JIT

Tags: java, jit

Are there ways to visualize the results of the JIT for a particular function, once suitably warmed-up? I'd like to see if, for example, the JIT ever optimizes out calls to the `java.nio` Buffer accessors.

Comment: Why not call the relevant methods in a loop and see if their durations decrease?

Comment: Because I'm a nosy person and I'd like to see for myself if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to consider using [PrintAssembly](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly) command line argument set.

> The following HotSpot options (with an -XX: prefix on the command line) require OpenJDK 7 and an externally loadable disassembler plugin

Advice to try [hsdis plugin](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/hotspot/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/tools/hsdis/README) implementation. But you need to build it manually.

To see generated code you also should use **-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions** at first. In another way JVM will not recognize another [PrintAssembly](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly) options.

In your case should help next options:

- **-XX:CompileCommand** can help to filter output for your application.
- **-XX:LogFile=foo.log** will help to log such kind of information in the separate file.